# Dock disappearing when using the Show Recents menu item?

Tags: macos, itunes

I just discovered that if I `Turn Hiding On` and right click on the iTunes app in my dock and press `Show Recents`, then my dock will no longer appear when I move my mouse to the bottom of the screen until I log out and back in. I have the latest version of Lion and I was wondering if this was only me.

Comment: I don't have the "Show Recents" option... what does it do?

Comment: @jtbandes: IDK. If press it, I get a launchpad-type effect but the screen is a bit darker with nothing on it.

Comment: Show Recents is an option you can use to show recently opened documents in a closed application.

Comment: @jmlumpkin Ah, yes, it only works with closed applications. It's equivalent to "Show All Windows" for open applications.

Answer (score 1):

This may be only you, which could be an issue with the preference files, etc.

Show recents (with a Dock that hides) for me shows the transparent dark screen, and whatever icons that should be there for that app, and shows the dock fully available.

Once clicking on the desktop though, to get out of this mode, my dock hides again as it should.

I would recommend removing the Dock preferences, which is located at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist, and then restarting the dock.

You should open the Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app), and then run:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

then run

```
killall Dock
```

to restart the dock. You may have to set up your dock icons again, but this may help the dock not showing back up after using 'Show Recents'

Answer (score 0):

To explain show recents:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3258198?start=0&tstart=0

Basically, if the app is closed you can right click on it in the Dock and have it show recently opened documents.

As for it killing the Dock, no, my Dock is in hiding mode, and I can show recents on iTunes and it still reappears afterwards.